# Binomial Coefficient through multiplication only

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Is there any method to obtain $n \choose k$, for all $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$, using only products of natural numbers without using recursion on binomial coeffcients?

A method that allows one to compute the following binomial coefficients through these operations, for instance:
$$ {9 \choose 6} = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 = 84$$
$$ {10 \choose 4} = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 210$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to explain this more precisely, because otherwise there is a trivial answer: yes, you just can write it as a product of integers left and right, i.e., as $n!=\binom{n}{k}\cdot k!(n-k)!$. So $24=\binom{4}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 2$, so that $\binom{4}{2}=6=2\cdot 3$.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Dear Dietrich, in this example of yours a division is implied. I am asking for a purely multiplicative method to obtain binomial coefficients, a method which involves only products of natural numbers. No explicit recursion to binomial coefficients is allowed as well.

Comment: I don't see how.  If, for example, $~n~$ is equal to the prime $~p~$, and $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$, then $~\displaystyle \binom{p}{k}~$ will be a multiple of $~p~$, and therefore have to have one of its factors be $~p.~$  On the other hand, (for example), $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{3}~$ is not a multiple of $~6.$

Comment: I doubt that the algorithm you seem to want exists. I think that what you are trying to do is equivalent to factoring the binomial coefficients. Division is implicit there. See https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1199990-6/S0025-5718-1993-1199990-6.pdf

Comment: Dear Ethan, I recognize division is typically involved in this operation. But there can be another way in principle. Don't you agree that there is chance ?

Comment: Thank you for the reference, Ethan. I had this paper in my hands once, but I went not too far in reading and understanding the whole argument in it. It seems the authors were mainly interested in obtaining estimates of intervals to search for the least prime factor of a given binomial coefficient.

Comment: This is a good question +1, basically how to multiply only the final factors. This would have to be done algorithmically.

Comment: Think about the cost of this answer. In other words, in order to obtain the answer this way, you need to start by solving the following problem: given an integer $n$, a nonnegative integer $k$, and a prime $p\le k$, what is the highest power $p$ that divides $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-k+1)}{k!}$? And in order to solve that, you would first need to come up with an algorithm to find all the primes $p\le k$ for a given integer $k\ge 0$. As you can see, the costs are starting to pile up here.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I see prime numbers are implied here somehow (and all the difficulties and complexities that come together), but perhaps the algorithm deals with another set of natural numbers other than the primes. Perhaps this set contains some prime numbers.